# Google AdSense's terms of service - Age below range

Tags: google-adsense, terms-of-use

I'm would like to use on my website AdSense's ads features. The TOS require age above 18. I'm currently 17 and will reach this age after 9 months.  Which of the following is the best option?

### Use a fake date of birth

I could take risk of registering account with fake date of birth (to reach age >= 18).  AdSense might find about this and penalize me.  I'm not sure what I would lose if that happened. Maybe a time ban or some kind money charge.

### Use my parents

I could use the account of an adult for example my parent, but I don't know if I could transfer the site to my own account when I turn 18.   See: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/0zaDdnmE0KM

### Summary

In both solutions I take some risk.  I can't afford to start this service without AdSense, and the service would not very useful to start in 9 months.  What is my better option?

Comment: Great.. On StackOverflow they ignored me and also here moderator find out its better to lock this than answer... Great feedback I ve to say as its my most important problem to solve. I will tell the truth, I dont ve any other ideas for this questions It's opinion based from position of experienced webmaster which I cannot compare to. If your rules of service seems it as some kind stupid write me straightforward how should I ask to fit this rules, I dont know.. Let's say I need answers for 3 questions above, if its better mark them instead of "Final Question"... Im quite frustrated now...

Comment: "Referring to taxes I will not withdraw any money before 18 so I will not met this problem" I'm not too sure your view of tax is correct. Tax is generally due whenever earnings have been made, not withdrawn. And Google won't want to hold onto your money forever.

Comment: And, on another note, you can expect no more than about €0.50 per 1,000 visitors for a blog. You'd need more than 200,000 visitors to make more than €100 per month. Is your blog realistically bringing in this level of visitors?

Comment: This not blog or any kind of open source site. I ve coded it fully myself and it is normal stand-alone CMS like website based on user generated content (AdSense's category entartainment). Probably you will think now one nerd created some sh*t and try to develop it, I won't argue - I'm only webmaster-amateur with some kind of passion to make something more than system provides for us, young people. In theory it is possible to reach, but I cannot give you any proofs, time will tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lying about your age is **NOT** a good option.  If Google closes your AdSense account, you are effectively banned for life.  Google will occasionally re-open closed accounts, but I have not heard many cases of that actually happening.

Relying on your parents is a good option.  The income would technically be theirs for tax purposes.  When you turn 18 you can open your own AdSense account and change the tags on the site so that it goes to your own account at that point.

Comment: Ok, just to be clear - I assume that I won't lose anything by rewriting my site's tag to new AdSense account. Btw, finally someone who do not try to avoid to help... Really thanks Stephen - marked as best answer.

Comment: Google doesn't support reassigning ownership of AdSense accounts, so all transfers of site ownership have to be accompanied by changes to the AdSense tags.

Answer (score 0):

You could just build your site for the 7 months and build up a following then when you turn 18 add the adsense ads.
Once you turn 18 you will need to change the ad units on your website over to your own adsense account.
Defiantly do not lie about your age.