# Setting up AdSense via parents' account

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, google-adsense-policies

My situation is very similar to the one in this question: [Google AdSense's terms of service - Age below range](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55148/google-adsenses-terms-of-service-age-below-range?newreg=169a2b2693a648d1a983d2ca4291fba3). I've already made up my mind that I would like to try out AdSense by having my parents sign up for AdSense, as they are allowed to.

I was wondering if it would be allowed to:

1. Add myself as the receiver for the funds on my parents' account, even though I am underage, the AdSense's account holder would not be. [You can add a different receiver for the funds](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6025222?hl=en-GB) as stated by Google's FAQ:

> **Can I set up somebody else’s bank account to receive my payment?**
>
> Yes, you can. Please make sure that the payee details that you enter in your payee profile in your AdSense account exactly match the beneficiary bank details of the account holder, otherwise your payment will fail. If your payment fails it can take up to two-three weeks before your payment will be reissued.

2. When I am old enough to apply for my own AdSense account, apply again for the same website, removing the website from the previous account (which would be owned by one of my parents) if required?

Unfortunately, I can't get answers to my specific questions here. It seems like they only provide support via email for AdSense customers who are already earning $25/week.

Answer (score 1):

The TOS requires adult to sign up Adsense, so your parent should help you to do so, preferable using a non @gmail.com Google account (bring your own email address, a non @gmail.com account allows you to change email address later).

Later when you become adult, you just update that account's information and bank details to your own.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that was possible. However, I would still like to open my own account when I can and leave the old one behind as it is legally binding to the creator and owner, which would be one of my parents. I would want to 'take over' the responsibilities by signing up myself when I'm 18, but I'm just not sure if that's allowed (create a new account with the same property).

Comment: @MaxKorlaar As long as you only use one account (set of Adsense code) at a time, it's perfectly fine. Websites can change hands from time to time and it's reasonable a new owner update the site and use a new set of Adsense code.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I am being extremely cautious with this as there's no chance for appealing a ban from the service. I'll have my parents create an account and I'll add myself as payee.